# Photon Gas Stress-Energy Tensor

Tags: general-relativity, photons, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In standard texts it is typically discussed how one can obtain the stress energy tensor of a perfect fluid, in both coordinate-dependent and coordinate independent forms:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{T}=(\rho+p)\mathbf{U}\otimes\mathbf{U}+p\mathbf{g}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)U^{\mu}U^{\nu}+pg^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
For photon gas, $P=\rho/3$ and thus in the photon gas's rest frame (rest as a bulk though each photon has no rest frame),
\begin{equation}
T^{\mu\nu}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho & 0 &0 &0\\
0 & \frac{\rho}{3} &0 &0\\
0 & 0 &\frac{\rho}{3} &0\\
0 & 0 &0 &\frac{\rho}{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
But I cannot seem to figure out how to write the coordinate-free formula for this energy-momentum tensor, since it has to be different (photon has no 4-velocity).

To be clearer, I would think that in matrix form, it would not even be diagonal thus I want to be able to write a concise formula the same way perfect fluid does, where I simply vary $U^{\mu}$ and work out the matrix. Could anyone advise on this? Thank you!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform What I mean is that the matrix is evaluated in rest frame of the whole gas, yes? What if someone is moving and observe the gas? Lorentz transformation is bound to say blueshift or redshift some photons and stuffs. The diagonal matrix above seems to me only valid in photon gas' rest frame. I couldn't write a formula the same way as perfect fluid, where I simply change the value of $U\mu$ in different frames. As for 4-velocity, photons have ill-defined for velocity but well-defined 4-momentum, since photon travels on null geodesics and hence $dx/d\tau$ is ill-defined.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Oh yes, I mistook $\mathbf{u}$ as photon velocity instead of bulk velocity of fluid element. Thanks!

Comment: would please put up an answer, it seems like it got resolved in the comments, but I don't follow. I'd be really curious to see the resolution.